# How to customize the will paginate links with images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I want to customize the will paginate links in to dotted images instead of numbers 1,2,3. I tried to customize the css of pagination class but it wasn't worked. Pasted below the links format.

(Existing) Previous 1 2 3 Next

(Need to implement) . . . **.** . . .

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but perhaps you still want an answer.  This is probably a good starting point.  Create a helper such as app/helpers/will_paginate_helper.rb with the following content:

```
module WillPaginateHelper
  class DottedLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
    protected
    def link(text, target, attributes = {})
      if target.is_a? Fixnum
        attributes[:rel] = rel_value(target)
        target = url(target)
      end
      attributes[:href] = target
      tag(:a, ".", attributes)
    end
  end

  def dotted_will_paginate(collection, options = {})
    will_paginate(collection, options.merge(:renderer => WillPaginateHelper::DottedLinkRenderer))
  end
end
```

then in your view use:

```
<%= dotted_will_paginate @posts %>
```

This is basically a custom link renderer based on the [original link renderer](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer.rb).