# ruby on rails will_paginate change default link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

In the `routes.rb` I set lists#index as the root:

`root to: "lists#index"`

I would like `will_paginate` to create page `href`s pointing to `/?page=#` instead of `/lists?page=#`. To create the paginate links I have the following line in the "lists#index" file:

`<%= will_paginate @lists %>`

Comment: is this for the coursera assignment ? :D

Comment: Yes. Since creating a custom renderer was not discussed in the course, but the tester scripts were expecting a non-default href output. I assume that they are going to update the tester files, because this is way too complicated for an introductory course. For the record, this was not an assignment, just a necessary work around that was not demanded by the instructions nor discussed during other parts of the course.

Comment: yes, I also found myself scratching my head when I was doing that assignment, clearly they should update the tests, it could be really tricky for someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question that you are trying to create a custom renderer, although I have never used it, but for that you need to override the link method of renderer.
here is the link to the original code might be of some help - 
https://github.com/voormedia/paginary/blob/master/lib/paginary/helpers/pagination_helper.rb

Answer (score 4):

The solution was indeed a custom renderer. Thanks Ayush!

The following helped me to solve it: [how-to-customize-the-will-paginate-links-with-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507639/how-to-customize-the-will-paginate-links-with-images)

I created a file: `app/helpers/will_paginate_helper.rb` with the following content:

```
module WillPaginateHelper
  class RootedLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
    protected
    def link(text, target, attributes = {})
      if target.is_a? Fixnum
        attributes[:rel] = ""
        target = "/?page=#{target}"
      end
      attributes[:href] = target
      tag(:a, text, attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, I updated the index file and replaced:

```
<%= will_paginate @lists %>
```

with:

```
<%= will_paginate @lists, renderer: WillPaginateHelper::RootedLinkRenderer %>
```

So the href is `http://localhost:3000/?page=2` and not `http://localhost:3000/lists?page=2`.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case the links are influenced by the order of the routing instructions in the routes.rb file.

If you place the line

```
    root to: "lists#index"
```

at the top of routes.rb then `will_paginate` will generate links to `/?page=#` without the need for a custom renderer.

This can be found in the FAQs for the module in coursera.

Comment: Thanks!

Yes, it also works if you put the `root to:` command at the top of `routes.rb`. Although, I could not find this information in the documentations I've checked. Probably, this was added to the FAQs after we asked the question in the discussion forum.